# Accessing different level of multi-level index, then convert column for this index to an array, to then pass to function

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have dataframe. A snippet can be seen bellow:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'EVENT_ID': [112335580,112335580,112335580,112335580,112335580,112335580,112335580,112335580, 112335582,
                         112335582,112335582,112335582,112335582,112335582,112335582,112335582,112335582,112335582,
                         112335582,112335582,112335582],

     'SELECTION_ID': [6356576,2554439,2503211,6297034,4233251,2522967,5284417,7660920,8112876,7546023,8175276,8145908,
                      8175274,7300754,8065540,8175275,8106158,8086265,2291406,8065533,8125015],

     'BSP': [5.080818565,6.651493872,6.374683435,24.69510797,7.776082305,11.73219964,270.0383021,4,8.294425408,335.3223613,
             14.06040142,2.423340019,126.7205863,70.53780982,21.3328554,225.2711962,92.25113066,193.0151362,3.775394142,
             95.3786641,17.86333041],

      'WIN_LOSE':[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['EVENT_ID', 'SELECTION_ID', 'BSP','WIN_LOSE'])

df.set_index(['EVENT_ID', 'SELECTION_ID'], inplace=True)
df.sortlevel(level=0, ascending=True, sort_remaining=True)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['EVENT_ID', 'SELECTION_ID', 'BSP','WIN_LOSE'])
df = df.sort_values(["EVENT_ID","BSP"])
df.set_index(['EVENT_ID', 'SELECTION_ID'], inplace=True)

df['Win_Percentage'] = 1/df['BSP']

df['Lose_Percentage'] = 1 - df['Win_Percentage']
```

For each EVENT_ID, so index level zero, I would like to fit an equation of a line, exponential, power and log based on Lose_Percentage column.

So the fitted lines for EVENT_ID 112335580 would be based on the points (1, 0.750000), (2, 0.803181), (3, 0.843129), (4, 0.849658), (5, 0.871401), (6, 0.914764), (7, 0.959506), (8, 0.996297). This would then be done for all other EVENT_ID indexes.

To try and do this I want to convert Lose_Percentage column into an array for each EVENT_ID. To do this I have tried the following:I want to convert `Lose_Percentage` column into an array for each `EVENT_ID`. To do this I have tried the following:

```
df["Lose_Percentage"][112335580].tolist()
```

I don't want to just access one I want to access each value in the `Lose_Percentage` column for each `EVENT_ID` and pass this list to a function.

To fit a line to the data I can use polyfit. So I will need to pass the array to this.

Also, I have had a look to see how I can fit log, power and exponential line but cannot find a function which can do this

Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Sandy

Comment: These are 2 separate questions - I suggest you move the question about how to fit different curves to a separate post

Comment: You should update `pandas` because `sortlevel` is deprecated and doesn't work in 0.24.1 (use `sort_index`instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to extract the values. At first you define a function which fits and evaluates

```
def fit_eval(df):
    y = df.values
    x = np.arange(0, len(y)) + 1
    z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    p = np.poly1d(z)
    return p(x)
```

This function can be used in a groupy:

```
df['fit'] = df.groupby(level=0)['Lose_Percentage'].transform(fit_eval)
```

Comment: Just to clarify:

The values in the data frame are taken and assigned to variable y. 

The x variable creates an array of the values.

The z variable stores the fitted line.

P then finds the roots of this line and returns the value this. 

When the function is called the values are added as a new column in the data frame.

Is what I stated above in line with your code?

Comment: That's not completely right, have a look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html this will make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the required list  by using `loc` -

```
extract = pd.Series(df.loc[112335580]["Lose_Percentage"])
extract.reset_index()
```

Comment: This only access one index. I want to access each index and convert the column "Lose_Percentage" to separate arrays.